# Oops, filename.json doesn't seem to exist | Creating filename.json with some default data

Tags: node.js, web-api-testing, json-server

I am learning API testing, so I have created JSON file, and trying to create an API which will display the data found in JSON file into browser, but getting

> Oops, filename.json doesn't seem to exist
> Creating filename.json with some default data

I navigated via CMD to where the JSON file is present, and then ran command: `json-server --watch abcd.json` but getting below output:

```
  Loading abcd.json
  Oops, abcd.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating abcd.json with some default data

  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/posts
  http://localhost:3000/comments
  http://localhost:3000/profile

  Home
  http://localhost:3000
```

I was expecting output to get below URL, which if i run i would get the content of JSON file on browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/abcd
```

here abcd is the JSON file which i created.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're executing?

Comment: I am just trying to replicate and learn what this sir is doing in this video. https://youtu.be/tnpqR7Ar-BQ?si=zBHrirt3emvyi4Me